# ¿Cómo abrir un archivo a partir de un printf?

Tags: c, string, archivo

El problema me pide que introduzca con un printf el nombre del archivo y de la extensión, y a partir de ahí que se abra el archivo y aparezca lo que hay dentro de él. No sé como hacer para poner las cadenas que recojo a partir del printf en la parte de abrir el archivo, ya que poniendo %s, %s no me funciona.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {

    char arquivo[50];
    char extension[10];

}Estrutura;

int main() {

    Estrutura Est;

    Est.arquivo;
    Est.extension;

    printf("\n\nIntroduzca el nombre del archivo. : ");
    scanf("%s", Est.arquivo);

    printf("\n\nIntroduzca la extension del archivo: ");
    scanf("%s", Est.extension);

    FILE *f;

    if ((f = fopen("%s.%s", "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(f, "\n\nNo fue posible abrir el fichero. \n\n");
    } else {
        printf("\n\n%s.%s", Est.arquivo, Est.extension);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `fopen("%s.%s")` no funciona como crees. En `printf` sí funciona porque es la función la que da formato. Tienes que combinar las cadenas manualmente. Estos links te pueden ser útiles: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4306186/13419694 https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: Hola, estuve revisando el link pero no encuentro lo que necesito. Como podría hacer para que el nombre del archivo sea el que yo introduzco por teclado?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que unir las cadenas manualmente.

Por ejemplo, usando la función [`sprintf_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) para guardar texto con formato a un buffer. Así:

```
char archivo[61];
sprintf_s(archivo, "%s.%s", Est.arquivo, Est.extension);
```

Para abrir el archivo lo haces con `fopen(archivo, ...)`.

Comment: No sé por qué todavía no me funciona, tengo: `char archivo[80];
    sprintf_s(archivo, "%s.%s", Est.arquivo, Est.extension);


    if ((f = fopen(archivo, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("\n\nNo fue posible abrir el fichero. \n\n");
    } else {
        printf("\n\n");
        while (!feof(f)) {
            cadena = fgetc(f);
            printf("%c", cadena);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }`